# Windows 10 Preview as Fusion Guest VM

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion, windows-10-preview

I tried to install `Windows 10 Insider Preview (x64) - Build 10074` in a VMware Fusion 7.1.1 VM but it always hangs at **Please wait a moment** (with the spinning *thing*).

Is there a way to get around this? (I tried to force a reboot but it does not recover and I get stuck at login.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the Windows 10 Tech Preview running in VMware Fusion 6. I did not have any issues with the installation. You might try grabbing a new ISO from the site or at this point, just waiting for the final version to be released.